# Finding innerText index in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose in an element where these are the innerHTML and innerText:

`innerHTML = <span>Hello</span><br><span>World!</span>`
`innerText = Hello \n World!`

Suppose I have an index no. (or group of them for a substring) for innerText say 1('e')(or 1:2 substring), how would I be able to find the index of this specific 'e' in the innerHTML.i.e convert this innertext index to its innerHTML index, 1(1:2) to 7(7:8) in this case.

Now I have an idea to do this, but I don't know if it will work or not. This is my concept:

Say in a function `textIndexToHTMLIndex(startIndex, endIndex, innerText, innerHTML)` we find which repetition of the string the string between startIndex and endIndex is, e.g.`textIndexToHTMLIndex(4,8,"<lol<lol")`, the string to search is the second(though the program doesn't know that yet) `"<lol"`(we are excluding the last index). Now after finding which occurrence it is, we convert it into HTML text, e.g.`<lol` turns to `&lt;lol`.

After doing this we find this new value in the innerHTML as the same occurrence of this string, so if occurrence_finder of `<lol` returns say 2 we find the second occurrence of `&lt;lol` in the innerHTML and  return it's index's. Of course while doing this we must ignore the tags.

Hope this was a good enough template for a function like this, but if you don't like it and have another solution, please feel free to answer. And as to why I need it - I'm using it to syntax highlight tokens from ESpree in a div.

### Edit

Forgot to mention this, but I have tried making the template, and am stuck at the part where I ignore tags, here is the code so far, though I am using it for syntax highlighting where I need to do the process differently:

```
function getIndicesOf(searchStr, str, caseSensitive) {
    var searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
    if (searchStrLen == 0) {
        return [];
    }
    var startIndex = 0, index, indices = [];
    if (!caseSensitive) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    }
    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        indices.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
    return indices;
}

function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\"/g, '&quot;');
}
function textIndexToHTMLIndex(startIndex, endIndex, innerText, innerHTML){
    var stringToSearch = innerText.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    var occurencesInInnerHTML = getIndicesOf(innerText, stringToSearch, true);
    var whichOccurence = occurencesInInnerHTML.indexOf(startIndex);
    var stringToSearchInHTML = htmlEntities(stringToSearch);
    //Here is where I want to keep a for loop which cycles every char except everything including and between < and >
}
```

Comment: Well, have you tried to do this yourself yet? I don't know about previous questions being downvoted, but questions like this which come across like "please write this complex function for me if I give you requirements" are rarely received well.

Comment: and if the span has attributes?

Comment: you forget to mention .textContent

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Forgot to talk about that, I have tried doing my own version however I am stuck in the part where I ignore <,> and everything in between that.

Comment: @epascarello By attributes do you mean what's inside the tags, well according to what I am trying to do I'm ignoring the entire tags while checking the string for all occurences, including attributes so <..... atr="...."> and </...>will be ignored in a for loop.

Comment: @MrJ I do not know what you mean by that, I do know about textContent (a bit). But how will it help in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally managed to do it!!! Here is the finished function:

```
function textIndexToHTMLIndex(startIndex, endIndex, innerText, innerHTML){
    var stringToSearch       = innerText.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    var occurInInnerText     = getIndicesOf(stringToSearch, innerText, true);
    var whichOccurence       = occurInInnerText.indexOf(startIndex);
    var stringToSearchInHTML = stringToSearch.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    var occurencesInHTML     = [];
    var isChecking           = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < innerHTML.length;i++){
        if(stringToSearchInHTML==stringToSearch){
            if(innerHTML.charAt(i)=='<'||innerHTML.charAt(i)=='&'){
                isChecking = false;
            }else if(innerHTML.charAt(i-1)=='>'||innerHTML.charAt(i-1)==';'){
                isChecking = true;
            }

        }else{
            if(innerHTML.charAt(i)=='<'){
                isChecking = false;
            }else if(innerHTML.charAt(i-1)=='>'){
                isChecking = true;
            }
        }
        if(isChecking){
            if(innerHTML.substring(i,i+stringToSearchInHTML.length)==stringToSearchInHTML){
                    occurencesInHTML.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    startIndexInHTML = occurencesInHTML[whichOccurence];
    endIndexInHTML   = startIndexInHTML+stringToSearchInHTML.length;
    return [startIndexInHTML, endIndexInHTML];
}
```

`getIndicesOf` function is referred to in question.